# Correct time in Django

Tags: python, django

in **settings.py** I use:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

On **page.html**:

```
{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

And I see **25th December 2014 22:40**, but now is **21:40**. The same problem with `auto_now_add=True` in models fields - I have wrong time (hour+1).

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the outcome of recent timezone chnages in Russia. Have you patched the server?

Comment: @J0HN I test it on my mac, the same problem.

Comment: It's physical timezone change, if you know what I mean. :) Macs need a patch as well, and it might not have updated as well.

Comment: @J0HN on my server I use `date` and it outputs correct date, but django use hour + 1. On mac the same problem

Comment: Do you have `pytz` installed? And if so, what version of it? Looks like it was updated in October 2014, likely to reflect that actual timezone changes.

Comment: @J0HN on server I have pytz==2014.10, on mac - pytz==2013.7

Comment: @J0HN: even an old `pytz` version can use the current tz database provided by OS. The tz database that is shipped with `pytz` itself has the necessary changes for Europe/Moscow timezone since `pytz==2014.7` version (1 Sep 2014). The tz database has the changes since [2014f version (5 Aug 2014)](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/NEWS#L357).

Comment: what happens if you run: `print(datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')))`?

Comment: I updated pytz on my mac and restart the server. Now all works fine. Thanks